# How do I programmatically implement the post build action "Publish JUnit test result report"

Tags: plugins, jenkins

I am writing a jenkins plugin using Java & Jelly script and wanted to automatically call the "Publish JUnit test result report" step at the end. I do see an option in the post build step but i am looking to achieve this as part of plugin itself. So that i dont have to exclusively call this step ""Publish JUnit test result report".

I red something `doPost()` method will trigger the post build action but wanted to know how to i call ""Publish JUnit test result report" as part of it.